# Assume that $A\subset\mathbb{R}$, $0<c<m^* (A)$, can we find a subset $B$ of $A$ such that $m^*(B)=c$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Here $m^*(A)$ denotes the outer measure of $A$.

I know the proposition is true for measurable $A$, see
[If $X \subset \mathbb R$ is measurable then for every $\alpha \in (0, \mu(X))$ there exists $X_\alpha \subset X$ such that $\mu(X_\alpha) = \alpha$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506193/if-x-subset-mathbb-r-is-measurable-then-for-every-alpha-in-0-mux-t)

But is it true if $A$ is not measurable? The nuance here is that we can't deduce
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to +\infty}m^*(A\cap[-x,x])=m^*(A),
\end{align}
as easily as when $A$ is measurable.

Edit:
The problem is solved.
Since continuity from below also holds for outer measure:
\begin{align}
A_n \nearrow A\implies\mu^*(A_n) \nearrow \mu^*(A),
\end{align}
we can see  that the proof is essentially the same as that for measurable sets.
See
[Continuity of outer measure induced by measure from below](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577602/continuity-of-outer-measure-induced-by-measure-from-below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\mu^*(A) \le \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}\mu^*(A\cap [n, n+1))$. However, since the sets $[n,n+1)$ are measurable we have $\sum_{n=a}^{b-1} \mu^*(A\cap [n,n+1)) = \mu^*(A\cap [a,b))$. Therefore
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \mu^*(A\cap [-n, n])= \mu^*(A)$$

Note: More generally,  if $A_n \nearrow A$ then
$\mu^*(A_n) \nearrow \mu^*(A)$, the proof is somewhere on the site, with a beautiful idea.

$\bf{Added:}$ The proof of the last equality, from an answer on this site, can't locate it now.

Take $D_n$ measurable, $D_n \supset A_n$, and $\mu^*(A_n) = \mu(D_n)$ (a measurable hull).  Now we can make $D_n$  also increasing: instead of $D_n$, take $D_n\colon=\cap_{m\ge n} D_m$ (  a wonderful idea, not mine). Now we get
$$\mu^{*}(A_n) = \mu(D_n) \nearrow \mu(\cup_{n} D_n) \ge \mu^{*}(A)$$

Comment: Thanks! My textbook covers continuity from below for Lebesgue measure but not for outer measure, so I was at a loss. With this new fact I can see that the proof is essentially the same as that for measurable sets.

Comment: @StackExchangeUser1: You're welcome! I added a sketch of proof for the equality in the general case